# XML Parsing in Java and Store Information

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm making a simple drawing program with slides in it and I have an XML file with the following schema:

For every slide, I store a line or multiple line segments such as:

http://orhancanceylan.com/stack/file.xml

I'm taking "Slides" with this code:

```
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Slide");
System.out.println(nodeLst.getLength());
```

And iterate by taking nodes:

```
Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(i);
```

But in my iteration, I couldn't figure out how I should take the line segment or lines only for the first node(first slide).

How should I parse these XML properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider using XPath to do the dirty work of looking up your XML nodes:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

To get just the segment from the first slide, the XPath could be: `//Slide[id='0']/segment`

For example, maybe something like this:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Slide[id='0']/segment");
```

Then evaluate your doc with the given XPath expression, and typecast the resulte:

```
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
```

That will give you just the first slide's `<segment>` node in your XML.  You can probably extrapolate from that answer on how to get more XML nodes using XPath.  See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to parse it easily, you can go for Apache Commons Config library which gives you the complete object.

You can refer the link below for an example, and navigate to the documentation to know more:

http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_beans.html#An_Example

You can refer the document below if you need to go with DOM parsing in Java.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152